# How to render/display or convert Umat efficiently, while GPU not support OpenGL but OpenGL ES?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl-es, gstreamer

I am developing a video stitching application on RK3588 Debian 11, using OpenCV. I have utilized the T-API strategy and achieved good optimization on the processing part. The inputs are four *Gstreamer* pipelines corresponding to four IMX415 cameras, and the output is one *Gstreamer* pipeline with `kmssink`. Currently, the performance bottleneck of the program is at the Umat to Mat conversion part.

- I've profiled the code with `cv::getTickCount()`:

  ```cpp
  while (true) {
      record_t[10] = cv::getTickCount();
      cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, 4), & {
          for (int i = range.start; i < range.end; i++) {
              caps[i] >> origin_dir_img[i];
              if (origin_dir_img[i].empty()) {
                  break;
              }
              srcs.push_back(&origin_dir_img[i]);
          }
      });
      record_t[11] = cv::getTickCount();  // 10-11 get read time 
      if (origin_dir_img[0].empty()) {
          std::cout  << argv[1] << " finished" << std::endl;
          break;
      }
      record_t[12] = cv::getTickCount();  
          out_put_img_U = single_opencl_process(argc, argv, out_put_img_U);
      record_t[13] = cv::getTickCount();  // 12-13 single opencl process time  
          out_put_img_U.copyTo(playframe);
      record_t[14] = cv::getTickCount();  // 13-14 Umat to mat time
          writer << playframe;
      record_t[15] = cv::getTickCount();  // 14-15 get write time       
  }
  ```

  And here is the result of one loop:

  ```
  ./avm_demo_opencl camera read time: 6.58554e-05
  ./avm_demo_opencl camera caps to src time: 0.0041943
  ./avm_demo_opencl camera single opencl process: 0.0125829
  ./avm_demo_opencl camera UMAT to MAT time: 0.0335544
  ./avm_demo_opencl camera write time: 0.0041943
  ```

I attempted to use `namedWindow(window_name, WINDOW_OPENGL | WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);`, referring to a solution I found: https://answers.opencv.org/question/38848/opencv-displaying-umat-efficiently/. However, since my board supports `OpenGL ES` and not `OpenGL`, this approach was not feasible.

[image: GPU support info]

At this point, I have two questions:

- 1. Is there any way or direction to reduce the Umat to Mat transfer time?
- 2. Is there any way or direction to directly render Umat from the GPU in my case?

Any help would be appreciated!